# неинициализированная переменная

Tags: c++, переменные

недавно начал изучать с++. можно ли заменить циклом while или как исправить ошибку в цикле for?

```
int main()
{
 int a, b;
 for (int i; i < 4; i++) {
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;
}

 return 0;
}
```

[image: ошибка]

Comment: Замените на `int i = 0` и будет вам счастье

Comment: хах, я просто ничего не присвоил. Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто инициализируйте (дайте начальное значение) переменной `i`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Когда вы пишите `int i;`, то в вашей переменной будет хранится так называемый мусор, который был в том участке памяти перед тем, как операционная система выдала его вам для вашей переменной `i`. Вместо этого вам следует написать `int i = 0;`, чтобы сразу задать своё значение этой переменной.
Если с помощью цикла `while`, то надо писать так:

```
int main()
{
    int a, b;
    int i = 0;

    while(i++ < 4)
        cin >> a >> b;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вы организовали бесконечный цикл.

Comment: И в самом деле. Исправил.

Comment: Не, не исправили, есть смысл удалить ответ и не позориться.

Comment: Нет, я исправил.

Comment: А может вам не позориться с утверждением бесконечности цикла? Ради этого я даже запустил этот мельчайший кусок кода, и удостоверился, что цикл конечен.

Comment: Учитесь у AR Hovsepyan, который исправил Ваш ответ :)))). На этом я с Вашего позволения, займусь более важными делами.

Comment: Ничего, что по факту он ничего нового не принёс? Он перенёс постинкремент в условие, а у меня было в теле цикла. И в чём спрашивается разница, а?

Comment: Разница в стиле :)

Comment: Нет, вы мне утверждали, что цикл не работает. Признайте, что вы не правы.

Answer (score 0):

Проверка равенства с нулем всегда быстрее и проще проверки  результата `operator<`
Поэтому лучше:

```
int a, b;
int i = 5;  // второй вариант i = 4
while(--i)  // ко второму варианту i--
    cin >> a >> b;
```